# I have two equations f(x,y,k)=0 and g(x,y,k)=0. I would like to plot the intersection curve in the x,y plane in Python

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I am working with symbolic variables x,y,k in Python, and I have two equations:

`f(x,y,k)=0, g(x,y,k)=0.`

I need to plot the projection of the intersection of these two surfaces in the x-y plane. I have found information on how to plot implicit functions using sympy. However, I haven't found anything regarding the graph of the intersection.

One thing that could be useful is that f and g are polynomials in k (yet not necessarily in x and y).

For instance, if you think in a simple linear equation g(x,y,k)=a(x,y)+k*b(x,y), then solving g(x,y,k)=0 for k would be easy. Then, we could replace that in the first equation and do an implicit plot in terms of x and y. However, g is, in general, not a one-degree-polynomial in k.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `f` and `g` are both polynomial in `k` then you can compute their resultant to eliminate `k` from the system of equations:

```
In [37]: f = k**2 + x*k + y

In [38]: g = exp(x)*k**2 + y

In [39]: intersection = resultant(f, g, k)

In [40]: intersection
Out[40]: 
 2    x    2  2⋅x      2  x    2
x ⋅y⋅ℯ  + y ⋅ℯ    - 2⋅y ⋅ℯ  + y
```

Now you can plot `intersection` implicitly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.resultant